# how to solve "unzip: cannot find or open" error in linux OS

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I tried to extract my file on the linux command line:

```
unzip myfile.zip
```

But this error occurred:

```
unzip: cannot find or open myfile.zip, myfile.zip.zip or myfile.zip.ZIP
```

Comment: Does your file myfile.zip exist in your current directory?

Comment: Remember that Linux has a case-sensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

`unzip` cannot find the file myfile.zip. Make sure the file exists in your current working directory. You can also try to provide an absolute path.

Comment: @Zay Ya Could you be more precise?

Comment: Yes, I use Cent OS 6.4 on VMware. I copied myfile.zip from window os by using samba. And then, to extract myfile.zip, I run "unzip myfile.zip"  .

Comment: @Zay Ya Copy your file to your home folder. Change to your home folder and run the command `unzip myfile.zip`.

Comment: Also t `~/file.ext` is unpalatable to unzip, you need `/home/me/file.ext` instead.

Answer (score 1):

unzip -d /zip osTicket-v1.10.zip

/zip is a directory
osTicket-v1.10.zip = zip file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the folder was not partially transferred.  I got this error due to an incomplete folder sftp.  When I re-transferred it unzipped fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your zip file contain space like "my file.zip" try to remove/replace space in my case i renamed "my_file.zip" and then the command (unzip my_file.zip) worked fine.